# CDATA using FOR XML PATH ('Category'), ROOT('Categories')

Tags: xml, cdata

I don't know if it's possible... I 've read that I have to use XML EXPLICIT... but I need to insert CDATA TAG into 2 column XML result.

### Now I'm using this script:

```
SELECT   
ExternalId,  
ParentExternalId,
Name,
CategoryPageUrl,
ImageUrl
FROM Cestino.acap.Servizio_03
WHERE ExternalId = 5763
FOR XML PATH ('Category'), ROOT('Categories')

<Categories>
<Category>
<ExternalId>5763</ExternalId>
<Name>Audio Video Elettronica</Name>
<CategoryPageUrl>https://www.url.it/s/audio</CategoryPageUrl>
<ImageUrl>https://images.url.it/n4897203.jpg</ImageUrl>
</Category>
```

I need CDATA inside field: CategoryPageUrl and ImageUrl.

Someone can explain me the right syntax to USE?
Thanks ALEN, ITALY

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
 1 as Tag,
 NULL as Parent,
 NULL AS [Brands!1], -- empty root element
 NULL AS [Brand!2!ExternalId!cdata],
 NULL AS [Brand!2!Name!cdata]
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    REPLACE(rtrim(ltrim(BrandExternalId)),'/','_') AS BrandExternalId,
    rtrim(ltrim(BrandExternalId)) AS Name
FROM Cestino.acap.Bazaar_Servizio_00 
WHERE externalid IN('100926550','100929174')
ORDER BY 3, Parent
FOR XML EXPLICIT
---------
I don't need CDATA into ExternalId...

Comment: <Brands>
    <Brand>
    <ExternalId><![CDATA[KONAMI]]></ExternalId>
    <Name><![CDATA[KONAMI]]></Name>
    </Brand>
    </Brands>

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

SELECT DISTINCT
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    NULL AS [Brands!1], -- empty root element
    NULL AS [Brand!2!ExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Brand!2!Name!cdata]
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    REPLACE(rtrim(ltrim(BrandExternalId)),'/','_') AS BrandExternalId,
    rtrim(ltrim(BrandExternalId)) AS Name
FROM Cestino.acap.Bazaar_Servizio_00 
WHERE externalid IN('100926550','100929174')
ORDER BY 3, Parent
FOR XML EXPLICIT

Comment: Another problem... I need to remove this:
xmlns=""

    <ManufacturerPartNumbers xmlns="">
      <ManufacturerPartNumber>V13H010L13</ManufacturerPartNumber>
    </ManufacturerPartNumbers>
-----------------
SELECT DISTINCT
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    NULL AS [Product!2!ImageUrl!cdata],
    NULL AS [Product!2!]
....
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    ImageUrl,   
    (
    SELECT ManufacturerPartNumber
    FOR XML PATH('ManufacturerPartNumbers'),TYPE
    ),